# Writing xml using contentHandler

Tags: java, xml-parsing, sax, saxparser

Using contentHandler I want to produce this xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Account xmlns="http://example.com">
     <Id xmlns="">123</Id>
     <AccountNumber xmlns="">456</AccountNumber>
</Account>
```

How to write elements using `contentHandler.startElement` such that I'll get it with `xmlns=""`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are talking about SAX:
[documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/xml/sax/ContentHandler.html#startPrefixMapping(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

You should use `startPrefixMapping()` with:

prefix - this should be an empty string in your case

uri - http://example.com